# Twitter Search Trouble

Tags: twitter, twitter-feed

Hi guys I'm trying to use `http://search.twitter.com/search.json` to pull feeds of certain users. It seems to work with most but I can't seem to pull justinbieber's twitter feed I keep getting empty results

I can pull wilw no prob

```
http://twitter.com/#!/wilw
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:wilw

{"results":[{"from_user_id_str":"20300","profile_image_url":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/421184034/qc_avatar_flip_normal.png","created_at":"Wed, 11 May 2011 03:23:19 +0000","from_user":"wilw","id_str":"68154189968191488","metadata":{"result_type":"recent"},"to_user_id":null,"text":"That Joke Isn't Funny Anymore #ValleySmiths (Thank you for your indulgence, and my apologies. Here endeth the flood.)","id":68154189968191488,"from_user_id":20300,"geo":null,"iso_language_code":"en","to_user_id_str":null,"source":"&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;&gt;web&lt;/a&gt;"}],"max_id":68154189968191488,"since_id":0,"refresh_url":"?since_id=68154189968191488&q=from%3Awilw","next_page":"?page=2&max_id=68154189968191488&rpp=1&q=from%3Awilw","results_per_page":1,"page":1,"completed_in":0.017642,"since_id_str":"0","max_id_str":"68154189968191488","query":"from%3Awilw"}
```

but when it comes to justinbieber (its for work sorry)

```
http://twitter.com/#!/JUSTINBIEBER
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:JUSTINBIEBER
```

I get [] results

```
{"results":[],"max_id":68133219333189632,"since_id":0,"refresh_url":"?since_id=68133219333189632&q=from%3AJUSTINBIEBER","results_per_page":1,"page":1,"completed_in":0.222307,"since_id_str":"0","max_id_str":"68133219333189632","query":"from%3AJUSTINBIEBER"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just getting tweets from specific users you should use the [GET statues/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) method instead of the Search API.

`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=JUSTINBIEBER`